# Fastest way to keep the last frame of a clip persistent

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have a video clip I would like that the last frame of this video clip last more seconds so the user can see it very well. Which is the fastest way to keep the last frame of a video persistent on the screen for a determinate amount of time without stretching all the video clip?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To hold the last frame simply drag the tail handle to the right. It will repeat or hold the last frame. If you want to do this in the middle of a strip then make a hard cut (not a soft cut) shift-k, this will remove the ghost handle, seen after trimming or soft cutting. You can then drag the tail out for a freeze frame again.

Comment: Thanks! I really needed this answered, and it was right there! Thank you!