# How do I create a freeze-frame effect with video editing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am using Blender 2.76b.

None of these suggestions have worked for me:

1. Doing a hard cut. I am doing this multiple times to leave a gap, which I want to fill in with the freeze frame
2. RMB to grab the right arrow, which I want to extend
3. Press g and drag it, which will create a freeze frame on the last frame if extended beyond the original size.

I've tried this selection and tried both g and e and neither work. It seems to want to let me either move it or make the clip smaller but not extend beyond its original size.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8979/599

Comment: By the way I should comment that the original way I was trying to do this worked. I was accidentally trying to do this on the audio strip, not the video one, and obviously this will not work.

Still getting used to Blender coming from FCP.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10751/37857

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add an Effect Strip->Speed Control, set the Multiply Speed to Zero and uncheck the Stretch to input strip length.

[image]

Then you can extend (<kbd>E</kbd>) the underlying strip however you want. To select the frame you want to freeze use the slip option (<kbd>S</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Comment: Instead of slipping the underlying video stream, you can also uncheck “Use as speed” and then enter the frame number into the “Frame number” field of the speed effect.

Comment: Still woking in 3.4. Good method, no need to render one frame as in many others tutorials.

Answer (score 12):

Because [OP's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42056/how-do-i-create-a-freeze-frame-effect-with-video-editing#comment71053_42056) that their method actually works might be overlooked:

1. Hard-cut the strip at frame(<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>)
2. extend it beyond its start/end frame by RMB+dragging or <kbd>G</kbd>-moving the strip start/end arrows - that creates copies of the first/last frame for lead-in/out

Manual: <s>https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/sequencer/editing.html</s>
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/video_editing/sequencer/editing.html#end-frame

Comment: Nice one, helped me thanks

Comment: For me, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could render out a single frame from where you want your freeze frame, and then import that as an image.

Comment: Excellent! I was hoping to figure out the standard solution but this should definitely provide me with a workaround. Thank you.

Comment: @BillGrant I think cegaton's answer is what you're looking for ;)

Comment: Yep - exactly right. Though to be clear I'm very appreciative of your answer, as it provided a good solution to the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The "add effect, speed control" answer works great, but the UI to accomplish the last part is a bit subtle for a newbie like me. After you have extended the underlying strip, to select the frame you want, select the underlying strip then "slip" the source video (S on the keyboard or strip, slip strip contents on the menu). Without pressing any mouse keys, move the mouse left and right. The strip will slide back and forth over the extant; whatever frame is in position one of the extant will be the frame shown in the freeze frame. If the strip is at position one or to the right of the extant, frame one will be shown. If the strip is to the right of the extant, no frame will be shown. Left-mouse-click or enter to stop slipping the strip.