# How can I repeat a frame n times and insert it into the main video sequence?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm making a video tutorial on how to use one of my python scripts and unfortunately I don't know how to do the simplest things. What I wanted to do is to just make a video of raw footage that I can cut into pieces at certain points. That way if I add subtitles such as: "Welcome to the tutorial blablabla" I can just take the first frame and repeat it as many times as my text strip is long until I continue with the rest of the video.

I've watched a bunch of youtube videos and read a couple posts, but I'm just unable to get my foot in the door. So I wanted to know how/if I can just copy my main video, cut the copy down to one frame and repeat that frame to make it as long as my subtitles stip. I already have the subtitles and the cut copy. I only need to know how to extend it. There are no handles left and right of my frame so I can't just strech it.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42056/how-do-i-create-a-freeze-frame-effect-with-video-editing  Question needs clarification, are you using VSE, what does the python script do?  The now defunct as of 2.8 blender internal render tag gives very little info.

Comment: What the script does is not important, I'm just recording a video of it's function, not using it to control Blender itself. All I want to do is to make a freeze frame of a frame somewhere in the middle of my raw footage so that it can be on screen for as long as the text strip is I inserted.

Comment: Make a hold cut, move the next strip away, grab the handle next to the hold cut and extend it, the strip will not be drawn inside, this is the freeze frame.